# Aggregation omiting values equals to zero replacing by 0

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have the next error. The idea that I have is obtain the min quantity aggregating by letters. But if the quantity or all the quantities are equal to zero get 0 in that cases.

```
letters<-c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
quantities<-c(0,2,0,1,3,0)

dtf<-data.frame(letters=letters,quantities=quantities)

dtf|>group_by(letters)|>summarize(min(quantities[quantities>0]))
```

I got this error message:

```
 Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = min(quantities[quantities > 0])`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 3: letters = "C".
Caused by error in `min()`:
! (converted from warning) no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I would like to have when the group has only 0 values  in quantities in the output a 0.
But I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

It gives a warning as there was no element matching that `> 0`.  We could use `fmin` to return NA for those

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
dtf %>%
   group_by(letters) %>%
   summarise(qunt = fmin(replace(quantities, quantities <= 0, NA) ))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  letters  qunt
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A           2
2 B           1
3 C          NA
```

---

Or create an `if/else` condition with `min`

```
dtf %>% 
   group_by(letters) %>%
    summarise(qunt = if(all(quantities <=0, na.rm = TRUE)) 0
    else min(quantities[quantities > 0]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  letters  qunt
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A           2
2 B           1
3 C           0
```